# Mail app not working on "smtp" error

Tags: ipad, mail.app, ipados

In my Mail app, on iPad 6th gen, there is an alert most of the time when I try to send an email. This also happens on my iPhone. It says:

> .smtp error, cannot send mail

On the other hand, there are no apparent issues or warning messages in receiving of email.

My email settings have been unchanged (except the addition of a mail signature and the disabling of the "send delay" feature in february) since I bought the device in 2019. I have installed iPadOS 16.1.1 in early February but I don't think it caused this since the problem has first appeared in mid-January.

The usability of the Mail app varies. It sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

I follow what the alert tells me do (Mail > Accounts and Passwords), but it doesn't seem to work most of the time. Sometimes I just get to accounts and passwords in the Mail app and do nothing and then return and it works.

Here is an image of the alert:

[image: alert .smtp error]

**EDIT**: I tried what @Allan suggested me to do (in the question's comments), here is the result:

- I was at home (but it normally happens at any place)
- My WiFi was a TP-Link-XXXX WiFi (the one I always use)
- I was using my only iCloud account (the one I'm always using)
- I turned on cellular connexion (it's turned on most of the time)
- I tried sending again.
- It worked.
- BUT, I tried sending another email to the same person (my other account (gmail)) just after and it didn't work...

Note: I tried a few times at different places with different WiFis in the past few day before this edit (March 11). I tried at school, at a café and at one of my friends' house. What happened? The same thing as in the five last bullet points...

Do any of you have a solution?

Comment: Can I encourage you to put some more work in your posts? See https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/ask-different-question-checklist for ideas on how to post good questions, and https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for the same with answers.

Comment: Sorry. I'll try my best for other questions. But I still don't get an answer

Comment: This is a global community, answers will take time. You can increase the chance of getting useful answers by improving the question. Right now, we just have the error message which doesn't help a lot. E.g. did you check whether the settings are correct, does it work on other devices you use, has there been any recent change to your device?

Comment: Also please visit the HelpCenter at top right to better understand how the site works and what to do if questions are on hold (and don't accept answers).

Comment: @Thinkr It is said in your post that you get that error message whenever you try to send an email but later it says the Mail app sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. Can you pls clarify if it the app never works in sending email or if it works only sporadically for that? How about receiving email? Are you able to get emails consistently on your iPad and iPhone?

Comment: @Alper , Sorry, I will edit this. It only works sometimes (sending) but I can receive mail correctly

Comment: When it stops working, do two things:  A) note your location and what WiFi you’re on and B) turn of cellular (Control Center, green button) and try sending again.  Report your results with an [edit] to the question

Comment: @Allan , what do you mean by my location? Is it the place I'm in right now? Sorry if this may seem stupid but I don't see what you mean by location.

Comment: Location as in home, work, school, coffee shop, etc.

Comment: @Allan , alright, testing and editing rn

Comment: The idea is to establish a pattern so it’s important to know where and when this is happening.  Now, there’s another account in play; one account works and the other doesn’t.  This is called scope creep where the details drip through complicating things as you move forward.  We need the pertinent info,  finally, it was to **turn off** cellular to force it to use WiFi.  Please slow down, take note of which account, where, and when this is occurring.

Comment: @Allan I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem Solved

I disconnected the gmail account and reconnected it to my iPad in the beginning of the week and, surprisingly, I haven't experienced any problem since!

It normally happened at least once a day and now, after one week without being disturbed, I consider this as resolved.